# How to identify distinct xpath for an element that occurs in different level in XML document?

Tags: xpath, xquery

For example, I want to find all the unique xpath of  element in below XML. Can you please help on identifying it using xquery or any other way

```
<a>
<b>
<identify>Level-1</identify>
</b>
<c>
    <identify>Level-2</identify>
    <d>
        <identify>Level-3</identify>
        <e>
            <identify>Level-4-1</identify>
            <identify>Level-4-2</identify>
        </e>
        <f>
            <identify>Level-4</identify>
            <g>
                <identify>Level-5</identify>        
                <identify>Level-5-2</identify>          
            </g>
        </f
    </d>
</c>
```

Comment: Want to identify xpath for this repeated element <identify> in the sample XML

Comment: *"find all the unique xpath"*... What do you mean by "Unique XPath" and why you need all of them?

Comment: am looking to check where <identify> element present in document, expecting below output  - a/b/identify
a/b/c/identify
a/b/c/d/identify
a/b/c/d/e/identify
a/b/c/d/e/f/identify
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/identify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml is invalid, but assuming you fix it, try this ([based on this](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_path-to-node.html)):

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com";
declare function functx:path-to-node
  ( $nodes as node()* )  as xs:string* {

$nodes/string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/name(.), '/')
 } ;

let $in-xml := 
<a>
   <b>
      <identify>Level-1</identify>
   </b>
   <c>
      <identify>Level-2</identify>
      <d>
         <identify>Level-3</identify>
         <e>
            <identify>Level-4-1</identify>
            <identify>Level-4-2</identify>
         </e>
         <f>
            <identify>Level-4</identify>
            <g>
               <identify>Level-5</identify>
               <identify>Level-5-2</identify>
            </g>
         </f>
      </d>
   </c>
</a>

return
functx:path-to-node($in-xml//*[name()="identify"])
```

Output:

```
"a/b/identify"    
"a/c/identify"    
"a/c/d/identify"   
"a/c/d/e/identify"    
"a/c/d/e/identify"    
"a/c/d/f/identify"    
"a/c/d/f/g/identify"    
"a/c/d/f/g/identify"
```

Comment: It works, and returning all the matching xpath. I can remove duplicates. Thanks Jack Fleeting!!

Answer (score 1):

There is also the `path` function: `//identify/path()` would give

```
/Q{}a[1]/Q{}b[1]/Q{}identify[1]
/Q{}a[1]/Q{}c[1]/Q{}identify[1]
/Q{}a[1]/Q{}c[1]/Q{}d[1]/Q{}identify[1]
/Q{}a[1]/Q{}c[1]/Q{}d[1]/Q{}e[1]/Q{}identify[1]
/Q{}a[1]/Q{}c[1]/Q{}d[1]/Q{}e[1]/Q{}identify[2]
/Q{}a[1]/Q{}c[1]/Q{}d[1]/Q{}f[1]/Q{}identify[1]
/Q{}a[1]/Q{}c[1]/Q{}d[1]/Q{}f[1]/Q{}g[1]/Q{}identify[1]
/Q{}a[1]/Q{}c[1]/Q{}d[1]/Q{}f[1]/Q{}g[1]/Q{}identify[2]
```

for the example in Jack's answer: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4P6ya

The format is ugly for XML without namespaces but in other cases has the lengthy but working format to work without setting up any namespace bindings from prefixes to URIs.